# Broken Eclipse Build Path?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons, buildpath

I think I screwed up my Eclipse installation while trying to install Apache Commons...

It is showing scary things like this, with little help on what to do...

[image]

[image]

The weird thing is I didn't really do anything apart from copying `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` into the folder with all the other jars I'm using...

What could I have possibly done and how can I possibly fix this? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like jre link to eclipse is broken.Right click on the project go to `BuildPath -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library` and Select `JRE System Library` . Now select the `jre` folder of your installed Java location and refresh the project. This should solve the issue. Alternatively you can create `softlink` to `jre`  folder inside the eclipse folder in case of Linux OS.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I moved all the other libraries from folders all over the fs to one folder in the project and just did Ctrl+a -> Delete, then re-added them.... didnt notice jre was there too :P

Answer (score 0):

make sure in the     `preferences->java->installed JREs` you have a valid JRE and make sure your project uses that JRE in the project preferences.

also you dont have to copy around. simply add an user Libary in `preferences->java->build path-> user Libarys` and add the jars you need.